# How to type GraphQLInputObjectType with prisma 2 types

Tags: graphql, prisma2

I have a problem with typing GraphQLInputObjectType. I can't find a way to inherit Prisma 2 types.

There is no problem when I type them manually for create, delete and other similar inputs, but prisma 2 has some very complex filters that are hard to manually type.

This is what prisma 2 where types are
[image]

Prisma 2 types for "where" property

```
  export type PersonOrganisationRoleWhereInput = {
    AND?: Enumerable<PersonOrganisationRoleWhereInput>
    OR?: Enumerable<PersonOrganisationRoleWhereInput>
    NOT?: Enumerable<PersonOrganisationRoleWhereInput>
    id?: IntFilter | number
    nickname?: StringFilter | string
    person?: XOR<PersonRelationFilter, PersonWhereInput>
    personId?: IntFilter | number
    role?: XOR<RoleRelationFilter, RoleWhereInput>
    roleId?: IntFilter | number
    organisation?: XOR<OrganisationRelationFilter, OrganisationWhereInput>
    organisationId?: IntFilter | number
    created?: DateTimeFilter | Date | string
    updated?: DateTimeNullableFilter | Date | string | null
    expired?: DateTimeNullableFilter | Date | string | null
    Seafarer?: SeafarerListRelationFilter
  }
```

StringFilter (Just one of many)

```
  export type StringFilter = {
    equals?: string
    in?: Enumerable<string>
    notIn?: Enumerable<string>
    lt?: string
    lte?: string
    gt?: string
    gte?: string
    contains?: string
    startsWith?: string
    endsWith?: string
    search?: string
    mode?: QueryMode
    not?: NestedStringFilter | string
  }
```

My manual typing of graphqlInputType

```
export const PersonOrganisationRoleWhereInput: GraphQLInputObjectType =
  new GraphQLInputObjectType({
    name: 'PersonOrganisationRoleWhereInput',
    fields: () => ({
      id: { type: GraphQLID },
      roleId: { type: GraphQLInt },
      name: { type: StringFilter },
      created: { type: GraphQLString },
      updated: { type: GraphQLString },
      expired: { type: GraphQLString },
      AND: { type: GraphQLList(PersonOrganisationRoleWhereInput) },
      OR: { type: GraphQLList(PersonOrganisationRoleWhereInput) },
      NOT: { type: GraphQLList(PersonOrganisationRoleWhereInput) },
    }),
  });
```

My manual typing of StringFilter

```
export const StringFilter = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'StringFilter',
  fields: () => ({
    equals: { type: GraphQLString },
    not: { type: GraphQLString },
    in: { type: GraphQLList(GraphQLString) },
    notIn: { type: GraphQLString },
    lt: { type: GraphQLString },
    lte: { type: GraphQLString },
    gt: { type: GraphQLString },
    gte: { type: GraphQLString },
    contains: { type: GraphQLString },
    mode: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});
```

Now the problem is that prisma 2 has many types and it would take a long time to manually adjust it to GraphQLInputObjectType. Especially when they add new things with each update.

WHY DO I NEED IT?
When passing args to Apollo useQuery/useMutation, graphql blocks the request as some prisma 2 types do not match my GraphQLInputObjectType. Types must match perfectly in order for it to pass.

For example:

```
//Prisma 2 type
id?: IntFilter | number
```

I cannot type  GraphQLInputObjectType as prisma 2 type, as I can either set it as  IntFilter or number. If it is IntFilter, I can't set a number as argument, even tho prisma 2 accepts both values.

Is there a simple way to inherit those properties inside GraphQLInputObjectType?

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with prisma2, however we autogenerated our graphql input types. Maybe [this](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/tooling/apollo-codegen/typescript-graphql-code-generator-generate-graphql-types/) will help?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll check it out